# Formatting cells in EXCEL based on real world date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to format cells in EXCEL 2007 based on the real world date for due dates on my bills. I know how to do this using Open Office, however EXCEL does not use the same conditional formatting setup as Open Office. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Cells A1 thru A4 contain text data; I would like these cells to change to yellow on the date that bill is due, then to red 5 days after that bill is due, and finally change to green when I change text in one of the cells that indicates I have paid that bill.

Is this possible, if so I don't get how to do it.

Thank you in advance for helping me with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing where you're storing the due date for the bills, I will assume it's in column B

Select column A and in the home tab of excel, go to [conditional formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286672(v=office.11).aspx) - highlight cells rules - more rules. On the bottom of the select rule type, pick use a formula

For the format for yellow, use the formula -

```
 =IF(AND(B1>=TODAY(),B1<TODAY()+5),1)
```

For red you can use this one -

```
 =IF(AND(B1<=TODAY()+5,B1<>""),1)
```

One you add this, move the yellow formula above the red formula and check the box `Stop If True`

For green, if the paid column is in column C, use this -

```
 =IF(C1="Paid",1)
```

Also move this to the top and check the `Stop If True` box.

---

If you want the formatting to ignore rows with blanks in column A or B, just add a rule to the top

```
 =IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),1)
```

Select no formatting, move to the top and `Stop If True`

[image]